# Nested layouts are very easy to work with, why use another?

Tags: android, nested, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

Everytime i use nested layouts, my sweet ide shows the error saying "nested layouts are bad performance". So i dig up  a little why it is and found that it is the exponential calculation thing etc. Also relative layout usage over linear layout is suggested generally. But suppose the below code;

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:background="#cccccc"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" android:weightSum="10">

<LinearLayout android:layout_marginTop="9dp" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/sub_background_dashboard" android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_weight="4"
    android:layout_height="0dp">
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  android:weightSum="2"
     android:layout_weight="2.3"
    android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="10dp" android:layout_marginBottom="2dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"   android:background="@drawable/sub_background_dashboard"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_marginRight="3.5dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"  android:background="@drawable/sub_background_dashboard"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_marginLeft="3.5dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/sub_background_dashboard" android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_weight="2.7"
    android:layout_height="0dp">


</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  android:weightSum="10"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="0dp"   android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
     android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"  android:weightSum="3"
         android:layout_weight="9" android:background="#77000000"
         android:layout_height="0dp"
         android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:textColor="#DDDDDDDD"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="#00000000"
        android:gravity="center"  android:textSize="17sp"
        android:text="Snooze"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="#bbbbbbbb"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="17sp" android:background="#00000000"
        android:text="Dismiss" android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:textColor="#DDDDDDDD"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="#bbbbbbbb"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="17sp" android:background="#00000000"
        android:text="Cancel" android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:textColor="#DDDDDDDD"/>

     </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:background="#ff0000"
        android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout >
```

Think Linear Layouts as templates for views etc. This line of xml code will work for every screen size for portrait mode!!!. Calculations are already done, no percentage calculation needed(and implementation of it) from my side and everything covers space as it expected to be.

If i would use Relative Layout, for horizontal views that width calculation would be much longer and maybe would require dynamic side( I am not suggesting *doing gui in dynamic side* is bad, sure it is better even) *So even small nested layouts like this, is it ill-advised still?*

Comment: "no percentage needed" -- you are using `android:layout_weight`, which amounts to the same thing.

Comment: I have meant for "no percentage calculation needed(and implementation of it) from my side"

Answer (score 0):

I use nested linear-layouts as well, because its easy. But for performance you can better use GRIDLAYOUT. Android introduced it in Ice Cream Sandwich to avoid nested layouts.

A little example:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:columnCount="2"
android:rowCount="7"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:text="TextView" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_height="16dp"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_columnSpan="2"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:background="#F90" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_row="2"
    android:text="Button1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_row="3"
    android:text="Button2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_row="4"
    android:text="Button3" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/view2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical|fill_horizontal"
    android:layout_row="5"
    android:background="#F90" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_row="6"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_row="2"
    android:text="HEADER" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/view3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="16dp"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|fill_horizontal"
    android:layout_row="6"
    android:background="#F90" />
```

Comment: Every row has different amount of widgets.. Can it still be done?

Comment: If you check this on android studio you will realize different widget sized rows does not look good as in my code.  So my answer is, is it possible to reach the exact appearance as in my code by grid layout? Copy that code ( change back ground of linear layouts to a color #ff0000 example) and see pls

Comment: I shall make it tommorrow and share it.